# Setting up CyberGhost VPN service on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have set up an account with CyberGhost VPN service and downloaded the configuration file and followed the [tutorial on their website](https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/779/251/how-to-configure--openvpn-for-linux-ubuntu-terminal) and now when I am trying to connect I get this error:

```
scooter420@scooter420:~$ sudo openvpn --config /home/scooter420/cyberghostvpn/openvpn.ovpn
Options error: --cert fails with 'client.crt': No such file or directory
Options error: --key fails with 'client.key': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
```

Comment: I don't know if it might be the issue: The tutorial said `Start the file manager, open your home folder and create a subfolder called 'CyberGhost'. ` you however created a folder called `cyberghostvpn`.

Answer (score 1):

`client.crt` and `client.key` are files required to connect your VPN.

The tutorial you link to describes how to download them (search the page for `client.crt`).